# Super Key not working with Gnome

Tags: gnome

I am using 14.04 and I've installed Gnome according to [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/189912/how-to-install-the-gnome-classic-desktop-in-ubuntu-14.04/) tutorial. I am currently using Metacity. Unfortunately my super key now does nothing. Additionally I do not appear to have a hot corner. Has anyone else run into a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial gives you the **GNOME Fallback** desktop enviorment. GNOME Fallback has **NO Activities** menu thats why you have no hot corners or Superkey functions. GNOME Fallback is GNOME 2's panel ported to GNOME 3.

It seems that your trying to install GNOME Shell (or Classic which comes bundled with GNOME Shell) rather than GNOME Fallback which you can find a tutorial [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/112620/how-to-install-use-gnome-shell-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

if you installed GNOME with your tutorial because you like the fallback-mode (the similarity to the old GNOME 2) and want to stick with a traditional desktop, you should definitively try [MATE](http://mate-desktop.org/)!
and yes: the super key is working in MATE like in Windows...! ;-)

Comment: or if you want the GNOME Shell, Hot Corners and other "new features" but with a traditional look, you can try [Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/).